# Jqgrid Datetime format sorting issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a datetime format returned from the backend(dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss).

JQgrid has column values as {name:'createddate',index'createddate',sorttype:'date',formatter:'date'}

but the sorting is not working properly

the result is displayed as follows:for example

06/11/2013 01:23:33

11/09/2013 02:22:34

20/09/2013 01 22:33

but the result required is:

11/09/2013 02:22:34

20/09/2013 01:22:33

06/11/2013 01:23:33

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `formatter:'date'` then you should specify `formatoptions` with `srcformat` and `newformat` options. Default format of input data (`srcformat`) which expect `formatter:'date'` is `ISO8601Short`: "Y-m-d". You use another format so you have to specify `srcformat`. Format of date which uses jqGrid is PHP format (described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)). So I think that the problem will be solved by adding

```js
formatoptions: {srcformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s", newformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s"}
```

More better would be to use ISO-8601 format if you returns data from the server. It's locale independent format. You can use on the server side `DateTime.ToString("o")` or `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")`. In the case you can change `formatoptions` to

```js
formatoptions: {srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s"}
```